# Only Second Screen installation lubuntu

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, multiple-monitors

i have an old (over 7 years) notebook that a friend of mine give me because the screen is broken. So i connect to another screen via hdmi and it's possible to use it. This pc run on windows 10 but it is too slow, so i think to install lubuntu but when the desktop enviroment is load, i saw only the cursor and no installation window. There is a method to set second screen like only active?
I am unable to reach the setting menu, i have tried combo: windows+P but nothing.
I have tried to remove the screen of notebook disconnecting the cable but the pc not boot.
I can enter in command line mode with CTRL+ALT+2.. but there is a command to install the system from there? It is possible to set second screen via command line?

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on your keyboard, it will show the search box at the top of your screen. Search "monitor". Enter the monitor settings > fast option > select second display only > apply and save.